# Exiting Java gateway on Azure HDInsight with PySpark

Tags: azure, apache-spark, pyspark, azure-hdinsight

i am using Azure HDInsight and PySpark.
Now a previously working snippet fails with the exception

> "Java gateway process exited before sending the driver its port number".
>   The pyspark source contains at that point the comment "In Windows, ensure the Java child processes do not linger after Python has exited.".
>   Even restarting the HDInsight instance doesn't fixes that issue.

Has anybody else of you an idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem, I logged into my HDInsight cluster via RDP and restarted the IPython service. This seems to have fixed the issue.